# Error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bannable' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Hello I'm cuurently developping my discord bot and I had an error with the ban command

here's the code I wrote for the ban

```
        if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "ban")){
            let mention = message.mentions.members.first();

            if (mention = undefined){
                message.reply("Member not mentionned");
            }
            else {
                if(mention.bannable){
                    mention.ban();
                    message.channel.send(mention + " was banned");
                }
                else {
                    message.reply("Impossible to ban this member");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: @FluxedScript it's in the title: `“Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bannable' of undefined”`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS uses `=` to assign values, use `==` to check a value or `===` to check value and type:

```
if (mention == undefined)
    message.reply("Member not mentionned");
```

Or you can use that `undefined` is *falsey*, so:

```
if (!mention)
    message.reply("Member not mentionned");
```

That will also work if `mention` is `null`.

As you don't reassign `mention` I'd also recommend using `const`, as you'll get an error:

```
const mention = message.mentions.members.first();

if (mention = undefined){ <-- now error throws here
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `mention === undefined`, instead of only one `=` (assigning).

JS is throwing off this error since it cannot find the property `bannable` inside the `mention` when it's undefined since the null checking was incorrect.